# Setting the Orientation of the device based on Height and width

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android

In my app I am having situation where all the phone will have only Portrait, Tablet with height = 1024 ; width = 768 then Height/width(1024/768<=1.3333) I want to make the tab Landscape otherwise I need to make Portrait.

```
String userAgent = new WebView(activity).getSettings()
            .getUserAgentString();
double screen_size = 1.3333333333333333;
if (userAgent.contains("Mobile")) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mEditor.putString("Device_Mode", "Phone");
        mEditor.commit();
    } else {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getRealSize(size);
        double height = size.y;
        double width = size.x;
        double aspect_Ratio = width / height;
        if (aspect_Ratio <= screen_size) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            mEditor.putString("Device_Mode", "TAB-LANDSCAPE");
            mEditor.commit();
            quit();
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            mEditor.putString("Device_Mode", "TAB-PORTRAIT");
            mEditor.commit();
            quit();
        }
}
```

Screen is getting flicking and app is getting crash at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen got flickering because it is keep on switching between the orientation. So I've stopped by

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

putting this line code in my manifest on the corresponding activity. So the activity flickering is stopped.

```
int i = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getRealSize(size);
double height = size.y;
double width = size.x;
double aspect_Ratio = 0.0;
if (i == 1)
    aspect_Ratio = height / width;
else if (i == 2)
    aspect_Ratio = width / height;
if (aspect_Ratio <= screen_size) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
```

By using this code I have achieved my task :)

Answer (score 0):

Check weather the mobile or tablet by using following code.

```
TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){
return "Tablet";
}else{
return "Mobile";
}
```